# Stranded Deep - Can't water plot

Tags: stranded-deep

If I have a bucket of fresh water and try to long press on a plot (which has no water), my character drinks the water. If my character isn't thirsty, it just does nothing. Is there a special technique to watering plots?

I also noticed that the plant, though dead, still produces fruits (although they seem to always be spoiled).

Comment: Can someone please create a stranded-deep tag? http://store.steampowered.com/app/313120/

Comment: Basic tag created.